# How can I reduce the verbosity of matching every call that returns a Result or Option?

Tags: rust

I have a case where I need to pull some data out of a TOML file. It's working just fine, but the vast majority of the code is matching `Result`s or `Option`s.

```
use std::env;
use std::error::Error;
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::prelude::*;
use std::path::PathBuf;
use std::process::exit;

extern crate toml;

fn main() {
    // Get the path of the config file
    let homedir = match env::home_dir() {
        Some(path) => path,
        None       => {
            println!("Error: Could not find home directory");
            exit(1);
        }
    };
    let mut config_path = PathBuf::from(homedir);
    config_path.push(".relay");
    config_path.set_extension("toml");

    // Open the config file
    let mut file = match File::open(&config_path) {
        Ok(file) => file,
        Err(why) => {
            println!("Error opening {}: {}", config_path.display(),
                                             Error::description(&why));
            exit(1);
        },
    };

    // Read the contents of the config file into memory
    let mut config_str = String::new();
    match file.read_to_string(&mut config_str) {
        Ok(_)    => (),
        Err(why) => {
            println!("Couldn't read {}: {}", config_path.display(),
                                             Error::description(&why));
            exit(1);
        }
    }

    // Parse the toml
    let config: toml::Value = match config_str.parse() {
        Ok(config) => config,
        Err(errs)   => {
            println!("Error Parsing config file:");
            for err in &errs {
                println!("  {}", Error::description(err));
            }
            exit(1);
        }
    };

    let host = match config.lookup("relay.host") {
        Some(host) => match host.as_str() {
            Some(s) => s.to_string(),
            None    => {
                println!("Error: 'host' option is not a valid string");
                exit(1);
            }
        },
        None       => {
            println!("Error: 'host' option not found under [relay] block");
            exit(1);
        }
    };
    println!("{}", host);
}
```

This seems quite verbose, and as I start pulling more data out of that files it's going to get worse. Is there something I'm missing that would make this cleaner? I know I could replace most of those match statements with `unwrap()` or `expect()`, but I would like to print some prettier error messages if something goes wrong, and avoid stuff like:

```
thread '<main>' panicked at '<actual error message>', ...
note: Run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` for a backtrace
```

Comment: Can you tell me why you use `Error::description(err)`? I see this code a lot and it's really not idiomatic. I want to go find the source and correct it.

Comment: I was basing stuff from here: http://rustbyexample.com/std_misc/file/open.html. Would the idiomatic way be err.description()?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should peruse the [error handling section of *The Rust Programming Language*](http://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/error-handling.html). The easiest thing to do is to extract the core of the logic to another method and pervasively use `Result`.

Become **very familiar** with the methods on [`Option`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html) and [`Result`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html). Methods like `map`, `map_err`, `ok_or`, are *extremely useful*. The lynchpin is the `?` operator (previously the [`try!` macro](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.try!.html)).

```
use std::env;
use std::error::Error;
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::prelude::*;

extern crate toml;

fn inner_main() -> Result<(), Box<Error>> {
    let mut config_path = env::home_dir().ok_or("Could not find home directory")?;

    config_path.push(".relay");
    config_path.set_extension("toml");

    let mut file = File::open(&config_path)
        .map_err(|e| format!("Could not open {}: {}", config_path.display(), e))?;

    let mut config_str = String::new();
    file.read_to_string(&mut config_str)
        .map_err(|e| format!("Couldn't read {}: {}", config_path.display(), e))?;

    let config: toml::Value = config_str
        .parse()
        .map_err(|e| format!("Error parsing config file: {}", e))?;

    let relay = config.get("relay").ok_or("[relay] block not found")?;

    let host = relay
        .get("host")
        .ok_or("'host' option not found under [relay] block")?;

    let host = host.as_str()
        .map(ToString::to_string)
        .ok_or("'host' option is not a valid string")?;

    println!("{}", host);

    Ok(())
}

fn main() {
    inner_main().expect("Error")
}
```

Check out crates like [quick-error](https://github.com/tailhook/quick-error) that allow you to easily make your own error enumerations.